# Counting in a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a fairly complicated join query that I use with my database. Upon running it I end up with results that contain an baseID and a bunch of other fields. I then want to take this baseID and determine how many times it occurs in a table like this:

```
TableToBeCounted (One to Many)
{
     baseID,
     childID
}
```

How do I perform a linq query that still uses the query I already have and then JOINs the count() with the baseID?

Something like this in untested linq code:

```
from k in db.Kingdom
join p in db.Phylum on k.KingdomID equals p.KingdomID
where p.PhylumID == "Something"
join c in db.Class on p.PhylumID equals c.PhylumID
select new {c.ClassID, c.Name};
```

I then want to take that code and count how many orders are nested within each class. I then want to append a column using linq so that my final select looks like this:

```
select new {c.ClassID, c.Name, o.Count()}//Or something like that.
```

The entire example is based upon the Biological Classification system.

Assume for the example that I have multiple tables:

```
Kingdom
|--Phylum
    |--Class
       |--Order
```

Each Phylum has a Phylum ID and a Kingdom ID. Meaning that all phylum are a subset of a kingdom. All Orders are subsets of a Class ID. I want to count how many Orders below to each class.

Comment: feel free to up-vote answers that helped you, in addition to marking the best one as the 'accepted answer'. It's part of the reputation system at StackOverflow. People are rewarded with rep with votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select new {c.ClassID, c.Name, (from o in orders where o.classId == c.ClassId select o).Count()}
```

Is this possible for you? Best I can do without knowing more of the arch.

Comment: I get this error for the `(from o in orders...)` section: `Error 16 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Comment: I got the right idea, but the code above will not compile (at least in my situation)  It needs to add a a named property: `select new {c.ClassID, c.Name, **Count**=from o in orders where o.classId == c.ClassId select o).Count()}`

Answer (score 0):

If the relationships are as you describe:

```
  var foo = db.Class.Where(c=>c.Phylum.PhylumID == "something")
                    .Select(x=> new { ClassID = x.ClassID, 
                                      ClassName = x.Name, 
                                      NumOrders= x.Order.Count})
                    .ToList();
```

Side question: why are you joining those entities? Shouldn't they naturally be FK'd, thereby not requiring an explicit join?

Comment: I didn't try your code because I got my situation to work, but thanks for the FK stuff.  It becomes really easy to traverse through linq.  I have a little void in my datatables, with a many-to-many that still requires a join however; which is fine.